# Problema al hacer submit post

Tags: php, javascript, html, angularjs

Buenas tardes.

Estoy intentando realizar un submit con POST a una URL "vista.html", pero obtengo el error "Cannot post 404 not found". Sin embargo, al realizar el submit con GET, no hay problema.

El submit es como el de este ejemplo https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_submit, pero cambiando 
 `<form action="/action_page.php">`
por 
`<form action="vista.html">`

¿Cómo podría resolverlo?, y una vez que no haya problema, ¿cómo puedo obtener esos datos del post?
Gracias

Comment: No tiene sentido enviar los datos del formulario a una pagina HTML, lo que se hace es enviarlos a otra página PHP para hacer operaciones con ellos, como por ejemplo: guardarlos en una base de datos. Para acceder a los datos que envías mediante el método POST, tendrías que utilizar la variable superglobal `$_POST` con su clave, que es la misma que el atributo `name` que tienen tus campos (`input`) del formulario. Entonces, si tenes un `<input name="a">` en el archivo PHP vas a colocar `var = $_POST["a"]`